# SwiftUI, Alert disrupts NavigationLink?

Tags: swiftui, alert, swiftui-navigationlink

previous threads on this question have non-swift answers that I can't figure out how to implement in SwiftUI.  Please note that I'm using Xcode 12.5.

I created a playground in an attempt to post a "demo" version of the code, but wouldn't you know it, the playground runs flawlessly.  So, going to post little bits of the code without making your eyes bleed.  I'm getting this warning:

**pushViewController:animated: called on <*TtGC7SwiftUI41StyleContextSplitViewNavigationControllerVS_19SidebarStyleContext* 0x103021c00> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated**.

Here's how the code operates:

Navigate from View A to View B.  In View A's NavigationLink, I run this:

```
            NavigationLink(destination: MainScreen(user: user)) {
                CapsuleButtonView(txt: "LOGIN")
            }.simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                user.login()
            })
            .padding([.leading, .bottom, .trailing])
```

user.login() checks to see if the username and password are entered (bindings).  If not, it flips a @Published Bool which the view that runs the above code uses to trigger the alert message:

```
.alert(isPresented: $user.alert, content: {
    Alert(title: Text("Message"), message: Text(user.alertMsg), dismissButton: .destructive(Text("Ok")))
})
```

The Alert pops as it should, but I think it does it after the NavigationLink has started to navigate away from View A to View B.  So, after the Alert pops, the NavigationLink's simultaneousGesture block still runs the code in it (I checked with print statement), but does **NOT** navigate to View B.

Thanks for your help guys.  After 3 days of looking a this, I'm about to tear out what little hair I have left.

Comment: Ran my routine inside a Button vs. using the TapGesture of the NavigationLink.  Then used a boolean output from the aforementioned route to push the next view.  NavigationLink(destination: View2(), isActive: $navigate) { EmptyView() }.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `navigationViewStyle(.stack)`

```
NavigationView {
    //Your view
}
.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
```